# DotNet Highcharts DateTimeLabelFormat not displaying correctly

Tags: highcharts

I want to display the day of the week (eg. monday etc) on my yAxis and the time in h:m on my xAxis. I use the same datetime object when creating the data point.

```
new object[] {sp.ProjectStart, sp.ProjectStart, 79}
```

and I use the DateTimeLabelFormats as such,

```
DateTimeLabelFormats = new DateTimeLabel { Day = "%e.%b" }
DateTimeLabelFormats = new DateTimeLabel { Minute = "%H:%M" }
```

However these will display the exact same thing, which is this case is H:M. If I change the datetime object to for instance DateTime.Now, I will get H:M:s:ms.

It seems like only the datetime object has an effect on the format.
Is there a way to choose what I want to be displayed from any given datetime object?

Comment: Have used SQl Server as a data source?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

The datetimelabel I needed to format was Hour.

So I just put

```
DateTimeLabelFormats = new DateTimeLabel { Hour = "%a %e.%b" }
```

instead of

```
DateTimeLabelFormats = new DateTimeLabel { Day = "%e.%b" }
```

I guess this differs depending on the datetime object you get or something.